# Remove % Signs From Url Through Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently receiving some 400 bad request errors on urls around my site which contain % signs. These urls are not generated on the website but have somehow been picked up by google.

An example url is

```
http://example.com/file/download/1/%s.html
```

I'm wondering how I can rewrite these urls to remove the % sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think you're going to be able to do anything about this. I'm assuming that because this is generating a 400, the `%` **isn't encoded**, as in, the request is literally:

```
/file/download/1/%s.html
```

and not

```
/file/download/1/%25s.html
```

Because the `%` is a reserved character, if apache sees the `%s` in the request, it assumes that the 2 characters after the `%` is a hex number and tries to decode it, and `s.` isn't valid so it returns a 400 bad request.

This request is *never even handed off to the URL processing pipeline*, so mod_rewrite or anything else you put in an htaccess file will never see it.